# Problem with migration Joomla 1.5.26 to 3.x with jUpgradePro

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I need to migrate an old website witch is using Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.x.
I updated Joomla to 1.5.26 and I decided to buy and use tool jUpgradePro from https://matware.com.ar/subscriptions/jupgradepro-subscription.html .

I configured everything and I'm trying to start migration but there's one problem and I need Your help.

When I start using cmd of jupgradepro there's one error message after using command composer install.

```
Cannot update only a partial set of packages without a lock file present
```

[image]

What can I do with this problem, any Issue? I was trying to search something in web, but finally have to ask You for help.

One thing that I can say is that this example is a test so target domain is a subdomain (http://ernestdolowy.pl/projects/szpital/nowytest/) and source site has just empty test template, is that a problem? Joomla 3.x is well configured on subdomain.

Finally I need to migrate Joomla 3.x to Wordpress but right now I have to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, and found this solution on my local machine:

1. In Joomla site, `xxx\administrator\components\com_jupgradepro` I copied the composer.json file to composer.lock
2. I started composer install command from command line (in Windows, not in built-in jUpgradePro). It installed all dependencies, and in jUpgradePro command line window the check site command worked fine.

Solution:
[image: Solution]